# O que é a interpolação de quadros de vídeo (video frame interpolation)?

Tags: algoritmo, vídeo

Lendo algumas notícias me deparei com esta: [Transforming Standard Video Into Slow Motion with AI](https://news.developer.nvidia.com/transforming-standard-video-into-slow-motion-with-ai/) ou [AI da NVIDIA cria vídeos em câmera lenta sem “gravar mais quadros"](https://www.tecmundo.com.br/software/131459-vicio-videogames-realmente-doenca-especialistas-questionam.htm), em que a NVidia usou um algoritmo que transforma um vídeo normal em câmera lenta, mas suaviza os movimentos no vídeo criando/prevendo mais quadros (*frames*) com interpolação e inteligência artificial.

Um vídeos dos resultados pode ser visto [no Youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjViy6kyiqs)

Então surgiu uma dúvida, o que é a interpolação de quadros de vídeo (*video frame interpolation*)?

Comment: Cara a grosso e curto modo eles pegam o que seria 1 frame e transforma em 2 ou 3 ou 30. O olho humano consegue captar por volta de 30 imagens por segundo, então a maioria dos vídeos é gravado em 30fps, agora imagina que vc quer pegar um vídeo que tenha 1 segundo, ou seja 30 frames, e colocar em câmera lenta resultando em 2 segundos de vídeo por exemplo. Ai vc tem que pegar um vídeo original de apenas 30fps e aumentar para 60fps, mas sem perder a fluidez de transição de frames para não ficar tipo um "stop motion". Basicamente entre um frame e outro esse algorítimo deve criar outros N frames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No contexto da pergunta, *video frame interpolation* se refere à prática de geração de frames intermediários entre dois *frames* de referência.

Considere a animação abaixo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela é composta de 3 frames, onde a localização do pixel preto cria uma ilusão de movimento. Entretanto o efeito é de baixa qualidade - você percebe o 'pulo' entre as posições.

A animação abaixo possui os mesmos pixels pretos, porém outros frames são adicionados contendo pixels localizados nas posições interpoladas dos frames de referência:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A técnica utilizada pela NVidia, neste caso, é uma versão extremamente mais sofisticada desta prática - dados dois *frames* as diferenças são analizadas e conteúdo interpolado é gerado.